# Using SCSS `@extends` with Deep Element Styles

Tags: css, angular, sass, nested, shadow-dom

Given something like the following, how can I declare a nested-SCSS-style module in one place and leverage `@extends` to define `::ng-deep` styling on a `:host`?

```
:host.tr.project {
  @extend .project;
}

.project {
  border: solid 1px orangered;
  display: table-row;

  .cta {
    .button {
      background: tomato;
      border: solid 1px cyan;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
  }

}
```

The styling for `.project` `border` & `display` get applied, however, *no styling is applied to `.cta` and|or `.cta .button`*. I **need** that.

I have tried different `ViewEncapsulation` strategies (`Emulated`, `Native`, `None`) with `::ng-deep` before and after different selectors and have had no luck -- maybe you have something I didn't think of (?)

Need some pointers on what my options are.

Comment: dose `cta` class inside child component? you need to paste your code to your question otherwise no one can understand.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
:host.tr.project {
  @extend .project;
    :host /deep/ .project.cta{
     // things goes here !
  }
}
```